# Saving a model using the PK of a 2nd level related field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass  # omitted for shortness

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class AB(models.Model):
    prop_a = models.ForeignKey('A')
    prop_b = models.ForeignKey('B')

class X(models.Model):
    prop_ab = models.ForeignKey('AB')
```

I want to save a model of instance `X`, but without doing `ab = AB.objects.get(prop_a=1, prop_b=2)` and then `x.prop_ab = ab`.

I want something like this (assuming that all the proper entries in `A`, `B` **and** `AB` already exist):

```
x = X()
x.prop_ab__prop_a__id = 1
x.prop_ab__prop_b__id = 2
x.save()
```

Is something like this possible? (the above syntax doesn't work, I've tried)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I need to do a bunch of `save()` of the `X` model in a foreach loop, so I also need to `get` the respective `AB` entries in that foreach. I'd like to minimize the number of queries I do through eliminating the `get` on `AB`.

Comment: Afaik this is not possible, class X needs the PK of class AB so you have to do a query lookup to determine that PK. But if you already know the PK, then you can simply do x.prop_ab_id = 1. But you have to consider that the optimization you are trying to achieve might not be very useful since a insert/update action is way heavier than a select query.

Comment: Instead of eliminating the get (which is probably the fastest query possible), use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/optimization/#insert-in-bulk) to optimize the inserts.

Comment: @Peter that's true, but I also want to minimize the number of connections (not necessarily the CPU time) to the DB. I will be using `bulk_create` like @Burhan Khalid suggested, but I want to squeeze this as much as I can. I will probably end up in using a complex query to `SELECT` all `AB` with one query.

Answer (score 0):

*assuming that all the proper entries in `A`, `B` and `AB` already exist*

you can do this:

```
x = X()
x.prop_ab.prop_a_id = 1
x.prop_ab.prop_b_id = 2
x.save()
```

*I need to do a bunch of `save()` of the `X` model in a foreach loop, so I also need to get the respective `AB` entries in that foreach. I'd like to minimize the number of queries I do through eliminating the `get` on `AB`*

```
for x in X.objects.select_related('prop_ab'):
    x.prop_ab.prop_a_id = 1
    x.prop_ab.prop_b_id = 2
    x.save()
```